# How to attach events in vue directives?

Tags: vue.js, directive

I need to attach functions to element using directives.
I want to do it with Vue method *$on*, but it's not working.
When I do it with *addEventListener*, *event.target.value* gives me unchanged value after first input, second works correctly.
How to fix it?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rjeu8Lc1/1/

```
directives: {
    rinput: {
      bind: function(el, bind, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
          vnode.context.eventListenerCalled = true;
          // wrong value on the first input in event.target.value
          vnode.context.value = event.target.value; //changing data.value
        });
        vnode.context.$on('input', function(event) {
          // never executed =(
          vnode.context.vueEventListenerCalled = true;
        });
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: @Bert I added code to the question. I do not know, how to do it more correctly. Sorry

Comment: It looks like it works to me. Both call indicators show up when I make an edit.

Comment: @RoyJ Two indicators are working, but input value not changing and _vueEventListener_ not called

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bert that you should not be trying to adjust the Vue object through directives. On the other hand, you *should* be able to set up an event handler. In your event handler, `event.target.value` does not have the updated value. This appears to be related to the fact that you also attached an input handler via Vue. When I removed `@input="setDirty"`, that got fixed. So I think the first lesson is: mixing event listeners can cause conflicts.

That aside, you can actually wind up with a facsimile of `v-model`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'initial',
      eventListenerCalled: false
    }
  },
  directives: {
    rinput: {
      bind: function(el, bind, vnode) {
        el.value = bind.value;
        el.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
          vnode.context.eventListenerCalled = true;
          vnode.context.value = event.target.value; //changing data.value
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-rinput="value">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
  <div v-if="eventListenerCalled"> Event Listener Called </div>
</div>
```

Here's a minimal snippet to illustrate the bug. If the Vue-style event handler modifies data, `event.target.value` is wrong in the JS-style event handler (which is called after the Vue-style handler).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'initial',
    isDirty: false
  },
  directives: {
    rinput: {
      bind: function(el, bind, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
          console.log("Listener called", event.target.value);
        });
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setDirty(event) {
      console.log("Dirty called", event.target.value);
      this.isDirty = !this.isDirty; // Without this, the listener works fine
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @input="setDirty" v-rinput="value" :value="value">
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
  <div v-if="isDirty"> Dirty function called </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _mixing event listeners can cause conflicts_  - so how can I do it without conflict? I thought Vue can resolve more than one event listener correctly. It resolves actualy, but after second input, so I think it is a bug

Comment: I think it is a bug, too.